# Why I can't get the warning messages as phpmyadmin does?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I can even use `abc` as the value of a `DATETIME` column .

Why is it not doing validating at all?

**UPDATE**

About how phpmyadmin gets the warning:

By reading its code,I find it's from `show warnings`,but I can't reproduce it in command line MySQL.

```
mysql> UPDATE `test`.`uu3` SET `id` = 'x',dt='ab1c' WHERE `uu3`.`id` =3 AND `uu3`.`id2` =4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc `test`.`uu3`;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| id2   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| dt    | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: phpmyadmin is opensource, welcome to add the fixes yourself

Comment: @ajreal ，it's opensource,but shoud be mature enough now,it MUST have its reason not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does the proper validation.

When I tried to add a value "`abc`" to the field "`date_time`" (whose data type is "`DATETIME`"), then I got this error **"Warning: #1264 Out of range value adjusted for column 'date_time' at row 1"**.

However, the row got inserted successfully, but the value of that field got changed automatically to "`0000-00-00 0000:00:00`".

I'm using the version 3.3.10.2 of phpMyAdmin.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you know where the warning message comes from in the first place?

Comment: Really sorry to say but I think it's the phpMyAdmin which should be emitting the Validation Messages. Also by default, it should be emitting the validation messages correctly, so it will be best in the interests of your future development, that you re-install the phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Wrong,I'm reading its code,it's from `show warnings`,but I can't reproduce it in command line MySQL.